# Not able to get response while sending my data to backend in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, response

I am using **axios** for sending my data using POST method.

**This axios is not giving me response on the console.**

Since, I have also used promise but still not able to get the response on console.

**Notice:**  I am getting the data which I sent...flow of control is not entering into **then()** promise.

```
import "./SignUp.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../SignIn/SignIn.css";
import Organization from "../../Organization/organization";
import axios from "axios";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      password: "",
      email: "",
      organizationName: "",
    };
    this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleOrganizationNameChange = this.handleOrganizationNameChange.bind(
      this
    );
    this.handleSubmitLogin = this.handleSubmitLogin.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFirstNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ firstName: event.target.value });
  }

  handleLastNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ lastName: event.target.value });
  }

  handleOrganizationNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ organizationName: event.target.value });
  }

  handlePasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  }

  async handleSubmitLogin() {
    var organizationRecord = new Organization(
      this.state.firstName,
      this.state.lastName,
      this.state.password,
      this.state.email,
      this.state.organizationName
    );
    const data = {
      First_Name: organizationRecord.getFirstName,
      Last_Name: organizationRecord.getLastName,
      Password: organizationRecord.getPassword,
      Email: organizationRecord.getEmail,
      Organization_Name: organizationRecord.getOrganizationName,
    };

// Code Starts here

    try {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/Organization", data)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(`Status Code: ${result.status}`);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
      sessionStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "email",
        JSON.stringify(organizationRecord.getEmail)
      );
      this.props.history.push("/sign-in/redirect");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

//Code ends here

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sign-up-container">
        <div className="sign-in-input">
          <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
          <div className="sign-in-input-inner">
            <input
              className="input"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
            />
            <input
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleLastNameChange}
              placeholder="Last Name"
            />
            <input
              className="input"
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <input
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.organizationName}
              onChange={this.handleOrganizationNameChange}
              placeholder="Organization Name"
            />
            <input
              className="input"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <div
              onClick={this.handleSubmitLogin}
              className="sign-in-button-container sign-up-button-container"
            >
              Submit
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

Can anyone explain me where I am lagging?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Medi  Nope... No error

Comment: Can you check in the network panel if the request is made and if so, if it completes successfully?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Yes request is made and is successful with a 200 status code. But still the content under-promise is not executing. Don't know why. I am getting my login data on backend also.

Comment: can you add the server code?

Comment: You're not dismounting the component on sign in by any chance? maybe it just doesn't have time to execute?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Yes, sometimes it get executed and the data is displayed at the routing page. But most of the time I need to refresh the routing page for getting the data displayed. What should I do?

Comment: `this.props.history.push("/sign-in/redirect");` try moving this into `then`? Alternatively you can make the request from the parent component which will not be dismounted

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Nonthing happened. Even `console.log(`Status Code: ${result.status}`);` this is not executing. Whatever content is there in present into the `then()` is not executing. But the status of API request is 200.